Unexpected error when using "addto"
I have defined a fairly simple macro as follows:
vardef foo(expr p) =
  picture G;
  G := image(
      draw origin -- (300,300);
    );
  show G;
  addto p also G;
  % remaining text

When attempting to use that by calling foo(currentpicture); I get:
>> picture (see the transcript file)
>> picture
! Not a suitable variable.
<to be read again>
                   also
foo->...rigin--(300,300););show.G;addto(EXPR2)also
                                                  .G;show...

In the transcript file there is a small additional explanation: At this point I needed to see the name of a picture variable. (Or perhaps you have indeed presented me with one; I might have missed it, if it wasn't followed by the proper token.)
These messages are really puzzling to me.  Is G not a picture expression?  Looking at the grammar rules in the metapost manual and at the definition of draw in plain.mp (show below) I expect  my program to work but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?
def draw expr p =
  addto currentpicture
  if picture p:
    also p
  else:
    doublepath p withpen currentpen
  fi


Not at computer, but what if you use a temporary picture, set it to p, and then work with it instead of p?

Thanks for the tip, that seems to work.  But why?
So inside a macro where the argument is a picture, it (the argument) can be aded to a picture but the another picture cannot be added to it (the argument).
I accept it if this is the defined behavior, just can't figure out what makes it so. It's possible I missed something but nothing I read in the manual seems to indicate that.

The reason is that p is "local" and cannot be changed. I don't know if it is explained anywhere.

You can change your expr parameter to a suffix one:
vardef foo(suffix p)= <contents> enddef;

It will allow MetaPost to handle this parameter as a variable (a variable is a peculiar case of a suffix in the MetaPost/METAFONT language) and thus allowing the content of this variable to be changed.
beginfig(1);
    vardef foo(suffix p) =
        picture G;
        G = image(
        draw origin -- (300,300);
        );
        show G;
        addto p also G;
     enddef;
    % remaining text
    foo(currentpicture);
endfig;
end.



For the record, the manual actually does mention that expr parameters in macros cannot be assigned to:

Now I think I also get it about suffix parameters, from the manual: "...10.3 Suffix and Text Parameters Macro parameters need not always be expressions as in the previous examples. Replacing the keyword expr with suffix or text in a macro definition declares the parameters to be variable names or arbitrary sequences of tokens..."
So what other programming languages may call references.
